# How does SAX parsing method charecters() work

Tags: java, xml, methods, character, saxparser

I am trying to read data from an xml file and store them in a list using the SAX parsing method. My problem is when I try to store the values of my data using the `characters()` method. I am creating an object where for each element I store each value and some extra information for some later use but when I try to store said value it stores spaces instead. I tried printing inside the method and while it seams to go through all my xml file it prints only a couple of the elements and not even in the right order. So can someone explain me what I am missing?

XML FILE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CarModel>
<Audi model = "TT" year = "2006" starting_price = "33.000$">
<type>sport</type>
<horse_power>222hp</horse_power>
<drivetrain>quattro</drivetrain
<transmission>6_Manual</transmission>
</Audi>
<Mercedes model = "W222_S400" year = "2013" starting_price = 
63.000$">
<type>luxury</type>
<horse_power>302hp</horse_power>
<drivetrain>front_wheel_drive</drivetrain>
<transmission>7_Automatic</transmission>
</Mercedes>
</CarModel>
```

JAVA CODE :

```
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

      lvl_cnt++;
      System.out.println(lvl_cnt);
      obj = new xml_obj();
      obj.setLvl(lvl_cnt);
 System.out.println("LVL "+obj.getLvl());
      if (lvl_cnt == 0) {
         obj.setValue(qName);
         obj.setParent("root");
         System.out.println(obj.getParent());
      }
      else {
        xml_obj tmp =  objListofLists.get(objListofLists.size()-1);
        int lvl_before = tmp.getLvl();
        System.out.println("AAA" + lvl_before);
        if (lvl_cnt > lvl_before) {
           obj.setParent(tmp.getValue());
        }
        else if (lvl_cnt < lvl_before) {
            int j = 0;
            while (objListofLists.get(j).getLvl() != lvl_cnt) j++;
            tmp = objListofLists.get(j);
            obj.setParent(tmp.getParent());
        }
        else {
           obj.setParent(tmp.getParent());
        }
            System.out.println(obj.getParent());
      }
      obj.attributes = attributes;
      objListofLists.add(obj);

   }

   public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
      lvl_cnt--;
   }

   public void characters (char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {
     String help = new String(ch, start, length);
     System.out.println(help);
     objListofLists.get(objListofLists.size()-1).setValue(help);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `characters` method only prints the *text inside the elements* (no attributes), but that also includes all the *empty spaces*, *tabs*, and *newlines* that might be present in the document and are descendants of the root element.

If you want to read text that is inside a particular element, you should set a flag when you enter that element (in `startElement()`), then unset it in `endElement()`, and inside `characters()` you test if you are currently in the element from which you wish to extract text.

```
private boolean inTypeTag = false;

public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, ...) ...{
    if (qName.equals("type") {
        inTypeTag = true;
    }
    ...
}

public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, ...)  ...{
    if (qName.equals("type") {
        inTypeTag = false;
    }
    ...
}

public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) ... {
    if (inTypeTag) {
        // do something with the text ("sport") which was found in here
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can this method of boolean variables be modified in some way so that I can keep and store any attributes that I might have because I saw that they are also overwritten with null... I saw one post that was suggesting using Map<> but I am a newbie in java and it seemed a bit complicated...

Comment: Yes. If you have to keep track of many elements, you can use maps or arrays. You might also consider creating a class hierarchy bould to your XML structure. Of course, if you have to map the whole document, you might consider using an API which does that automatically, such as DOM, or even JAXB which generates the classes as well. SAX is a good option when you have to read a document sequentially and extract selected data. You might also want to consider StAX, which is also part of the Java SE and is somewhere between SAX and DOM.